# Google Cloud - Cloud Function - Function error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Frequently seeing **Function error: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing** in the cloud function logs particularly when there is a high amount of data ingress from the producer. Approximately around 1000 records per minute.

1. The function gets the message , process it under fire store transaction lock. If the document already exists, updating it with the new version of data else create new one.
2. When it happens the function's execution time is 5-10 times higher then average. Normally it takes 200ms to process a message, but it spikes upto 10000-15000 ms.
3. The document which is being written/modified is under a sub collection.

   Collection
   Document
   SubCollection
   Document

Data Flow:
PubSub->Push endpoint Cloud Function->Fire Store

Comment: The error that you posted could be due to several reasons. One is that the exclusive locking in Cloud Firestore is not implemented correctly. Another could be related with TCP connections used by RPC. In order to continue investigating, does the issue still persist?

Comment: exclusive locking , you mean transaction lock?

Yes the issue still persist,

Comment: What information do you get when inspecting the logs for these functions? Are you able to obtain any information related to the errors? For example, can you find info in the errors related to Firestore?